# CUDA, Immutability vs. Mutability

Tags: multithreading, cuda, immutability, mutability

I am a firm believer in using immutability where possible so that classical synchronization is not needed for multi-threaded programs. This is one of the core concepts used in functionally languages.

I was wondering what people think of this for CUDA programs, I know developing for GPUs is different from developing for CPUs and being a GPU n00b I'd like more knowledgeable people to give me their opinion on the matter at hand.

Thanks,
Gabriel

Comment: If people are going to vote to close, or downvote, doesn't it make sense to explain why to the person who asked?

Comment: Could you be more precise on the kind of answer you're expecting ? Do you have any concrete example in mind ?

Comment: Hi, it's a more general question, I am not expecting an extremely precise answer but rather to have an open discussion about the pros, cons, maybe it makes no sense (if so why), etc.

Answer (score 1):

In CUDA programming, immutability is also beneficial, and sometimes even necessary.

On block-wise communication, immutability may allow you to skip some `__syncthreads()`.

On grid-wise communication, there is no whole-grid synchronize instruction at all. That is why in general case, to have a guarantee that a change of one block is visible by another block requires kernel termination. This is because blocks may scheduled in such a way that they actually run in sequence (e.g. weak GPU, unable to run more blocks in parallel)

Partial communication is however possible through atomic operations and `__threadfence()`. You can implement, for example, task queues, permitting blocks to fetch new assigments from there in a safe way. These kind of operations should however be done rarely as atomics may be time consuming (although with global L2 caching it is now better than on the older GPUs)